# Excel: How to open Data entry form using VBA, when there are 4 tables in the worksheet

Tags: excel, forms, vba

I have an excel worksheet that has four tables, one for each region of the country (Scot,North,London,South). I need to create a data entry form which will allow user to populate these tables. Ideally, the form will appear on a different worksheet once a button has been pressed. I would like to have four different buttons, each linked to one of the four tables. The tables have identical columns.

What is the best way to do this? I can use Excel's built in data entry form, by clicking on the table and then pressing Form. However, this almost defeats the purpose of the form, sicne the idea is to have a user end.

I have seen tutorials for creating my own form, but I need information on how to populate different tables depending on which button was pressed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now its different code but you should be able to adapt it for your form.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Inp1 As String
Dim Inp2 As String

Inp1 = TextBox1.Text

Inp2 = TextBox2.Text

Range("B2").Select
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> 0
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
ActiveCell.Value = Inp1

Range("C2").Select
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> 0
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
ActiveCell.Value = Inp2

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem I have is that I have 4 different tables which need filling on this 1 worksheet. Simply finding the first empty row will not allow me to populate each table. Is there a way I can do this? The idea is for their to be 4 buttons, one for each table, and depending on the button clicked, that table would be populated.

Comment: I changed the code, now it should fit your expectations. But its just for 2 text boxes so you will need to do it for the rest of your user form.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I'm sure the solution above is correct, but its quite difficult to understand. I have managed to come up with a solution by doing a days worth of research. I will post it below as an answer for anybody in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Having asked the question, I managed to find a solution my self. I will include it as this seems to be a problem without a good answer online. The code is to be used in the example shown in this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5oXcct1mOUw

The code for the Submit button is shown below. This is the code for 9 or 10 returns, but can be adjusted easily

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Current")

'Add new row
ws.ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add (1)

'Populate new row
ws.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(1, 1).Value = Me.name1.Value
ws.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(1, 2).Value = Me.namecom.Value
ws.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(1, 3).Value = Me.cin.Value
ws.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(1, 4).Value = Me.hold.Value
'DROPDOWN BOX
ws.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(1, 5).Value = Me.fee.Value
ws.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(1, 6).Value = Me.unam.Value
ws.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(1, 7).Value = Me.capfin.Value
ws.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(1, 8).Value = Me.month.Value
ws.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(1, 9).Value = Me.comments.Value


MsgBox "Data added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Added"

'clear the data

Me.name1.Value = ""
Me.namecom.Value = ""
Me.cin.Value = ""
Me.hold.Value = ""
'DROPDOWN BOX
Me.fee.Value = ""
Me.unam.Value = ""
Me.capfin.Value = ""
Me.month.Value = ""
Me.comments.Value = ""

Me.name1.SetFocus
```

`